# nasm bootloader, why does where i define ths string matter?

Tags: nasm, bootloader

Im experimenting with writing a bootloader in nasm, at the moment it just prints a string.

```html
[BITS 16]
[org 0x7c00]

myString:
 db 'Hello World', 0x00

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

mov bx, myString
call printString

jmp $

printString:
 pusha
 mov ah , 0x0e
 printStringA:
 
 mov al , [bx]
 cmp al, 0x00
 je printStringB
 
 int 0x10
 add bx, 0x01
 jmp printStringA
 
 printStringB:
 popa
 ret

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

that works fine, but if i move the string definition to here:

```html
[BITS 16]
[org 0x7c00]

mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

myString:
 db 'Hello World', 0x00

mov bx, myString
call printString

jmp $

printString:
 pusha
 mov ah , 0x0e
 printStringA:
 
 mov al , [bx]
 cmp al, 0x00
 je printStringB
 
 int 0x10
 add bx, 0x01
 jmp printStringA
 
 printStringB:
 popa
 ret

times 510 -( $ - $$ ) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

it prints out garbage, im running this in bochs under windows if that helps.

Comment: think ive just figured it out, the processor is probably thinking the string is code, excuting it and messing things up. if i move the string definition past the never ending loop, its all good

Answer (score 1):

You are assembling to raw machine code. There are no data and text sections. Everything is interpreted as code, including what you insert using db. Hence **both** code snippets are wrong.

If you finish with an endless loop (as in your example) or a halt instruction, the data can safely be put after the code as it will never be reached. Otherwise you must arrange for the data to be skipped over.

You also need to set the segment registers correctly at the start.

Here is a corrected version, with early declaration of data:

```
[BITS 16]
[ORG 0]

;;; Set CS and DS
jmp 0x07c0:start

start:
mov ax, cs
mov ds, ax

;;; set SP    
mov bp, 0x8000
mov sp, bp

;;; skip over data
jmp L1

myString:
    db 'Hello World', 0x00

L1:

mov bx, myString
...
```

Note that in your first example, the data was interpreted as code.

```
db 'Hello World', 0x00
```

is assembled as

```
48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 57 6f  72 6c 64 00
```

and corresponds to:

```
dec ax
gs insb
insb
outsw
and [bx+0x6f],dl
jc short 0x76
fs
db 0x00
```

In effect this gets executed before your code. It is pure luck that this fragment doesn't prevent your code from working.